# drupal 7 - page template for view

Tags: templates, drupal-7, view

I have a view call products. it is output on http://myurl.com./products. Can I specify a template file for this view page so it does not take the template from my page.tpl.php

Answer (score 2):

Accepted Page patterns are `page--[front|internal/path].tpl.php` so `page--products.tpl.php` should work for your view page.

See the documentation on [Drupal Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) for more details.

Comment: Op says its a view, not a page. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/935/views-3-and-html5-how-to-override-output-for-markup

Comment: Op says, the requirement is to override the page.tpl.php on the view page at http://myurl.com/products.